Media Template creation Meta
Can we create Media template with using Resumable Upload API of Meta, if we have the https url of the media
We wanted the create media template using meta cloud api without using resumable upload api.
eg payload : {
"category": "MARKETING",
"name": "flig_confim",
"language": "en",
"allow_category_change": true,
"components": [
{
"type": "BODY",
"text": "This is your flight confirmation for {{1}}-{{2}} on {{3}}",
"example": {
"body_text": [
[
"Delhi",
"Banglore",
"20th Monday"
]
]
}
},
{
"type": "FOOTER",
"text": "To manage the reservation signin to travel portal"
},
{
"type": "HEADER",
"format": "IMAGE",
"example": {
"header_handle":"4::YX..."
}
}
]
}
Below is the example to create media template with header_handle info got during resumable api.
But we wanted to create media tempate without using resumable api, where user will provide the https url of the image/document and we need to create template using that link instead of header_handle

Hi, please see formatting help
